# Keeping task queues in chronological order in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, task-queue

In google app engine, as you add tasks to the same push task queue, will they all be queued up one after another chronologically? Or is it possible that a task could be executed before another one although it was added last? (this is all assuming they are using the same queue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. I can think of 2 cases where that might not happen:

- tasks can have different ETAs (in the future, for example), the order would normally be the ETA one, see [do google app engine pull queues return tasks in FIFO order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475174/do-google-app-engine-pull-queues-return-tasks-in-fifo-order/40478036#40478036)
- task execution may fail (for whatever reason) and they may be automatically re-tried with a backoff scheme (i.e. after some delay). Which means other tasks which normally would run after the failed one may actually run before its retry attempt(s).

Comment: "Which means other tasks which normally would run after the failed one may actually run before its retry attempt(s)" - Ouch. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Task Queues make no guarantees about execution order. In particular, tasks that are scheduled to run immediately follow a code path that can result in significant re-ordering. Behavior for push and pull queues is also distinctly different.

If you schedule tasks to run after a short time in the future, however, execution order is more likely to be eta order. Again, there are no guarantees, and you should engineer around out-of-order delivery being a normal, albeit uncommon, case. Failure modes would typically be a significant number of out-of-order tasks for a brief period, not an occasionally isolated out-of-order task.